# pyspark sql to_timestamp function formatting

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe in pyspark that has columns time1 and time 2. They both appear as strings like the below:

```
Time1                               Time2
1990-03-18 22:50:09.693159          2022-04-23 17:30:22-07:00
1990-03-19 22:57:09.433159          2022-04-23 16:11:12-06:00
1990-03-20 22:04:09.437359          2022-04-23 17:56:33-05:00
```

I am trying to convert these into timestamp(preferably utc)
I am trying the below code:

```
Newtime1 = Function.to_timestamp(Function.col('time1'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')
Newtime2 = Function.to_timestamp(Function.col('time2'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z')
```

When applying to a dataframe like below:

```
mydataframe = mydataframe.withColumn('time1',Newtime1)
mydataframe = mydataframe.withColumn('time2',Newtime2)
```

This yields 'None' to be displayed in the data. How can I get the desired timestamps?

Comment: How exactly you are verifying this? Provide full details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for timezone is a little tricky. [Read the docs carefully](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

1. *"The count of pattern letters determines the format."*
2. And there is a difference between `X` vs `x` vs `Z`.

> ...
>
> - Offset X and x: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One letter outputs just the hour, such as ‘+01’, unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as ‘+0130’. Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as ‘+0130’. Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as ‘+01:30’. Four letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, without a colon, such as ‘+013015’. Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as ‘+01:30:15’. Six or more letters will fail. Pattern letter ‘X’ (upper case) will output ‘Z’ when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas pattern letter ‘x’ (lower case) will output ‘+00’, ‘+0000’, or ‘+00:00’.
> - Offset Z: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as ‘+0130’. The output will be ‘+0000’ when the offset is zero. Four letters outputs the full form of localized offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero. Five letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero, with colon. It outputs ‘Z’ if the offset is zero. Six or more letters will fail.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([
...         ('1990-03-18 22:50:09.693159', '2022-04-23 17:30:22-07:00'),
...         ('1990-03-19 22:57:09.433159', '2022-04-23 16:11:12Z'),
...         ('1990-03-20 22:04:09.437359', '2022-04-23 17:56:33+00:00')
...     ],
...     ('time1', 'time2')
... )
>>> 
>>> df2 = (df
...     .withColumn('t1', F.to_timestamp(df.time1, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'))
...     .withColumn('t2_lower_xxx', F.to_timestamp(df.time2, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssxxx'))
...     .withColumn('t2_upper_XXX', F.to_timestamp(df.time2, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX'))
...     .withColumn('t2_ZZZZZ', F.to_timestamp(df.time2, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZZZ'))
... )
>>> 
>>> df2.select('time2', 't2_lower_xxx', 't2_upper_XXX', 't2_ZZZZZ', 'time1', 't1').show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|time2                    |t2_lower_xxx       |t2_upper_XXX       |t2_ZZZZZ           |time1                     |t1                        |
+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|2022-04-23 17:30:22-07:00|2022-04-23 19:30:22|2022-04-23 19:30:22|2022-04-23 19:30:22|1990-03-18 22:50:09.693159|1990-03-18 22:50:09.693159|
|2022-04-23 16:11:12Z     |null               |2022-04-23 11:11:12|2022-04-23 11:11:12|1990-03-19 22:57:09.433159|1990-03-19 22:57:09.433159|
|2022-04-23 17:56:33+00:00|2022-04-23 12:56:33|2022-04-23 12:56:33|2022-04-23 12:56:33|1990-03-20 22:04:09.437359|1990-03-20 22:04:09.437359|
+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+


>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For col 'time2' the pattern will be like below:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssxxx
```

Tested in Pyspark v3.2.3 both are working after making above change.

Comment: This still shows up as None for me

Comment: Can you add more details? Can you test the code given in one of the answer and see if you get same or different output?

Comment: Make sure there are no extra whitespace / unprintable characters in your data/string